# Facebook Graph API call not returning all fields

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making the following Facebook Graph API call in PHP

```
// graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

    $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
    $fbuname = $graphObject->getProperty('username');  // To Get Facebook Username
    $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
    $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
```

The API call is working. If I am logged in, then this API call returns my information and I can print my full name and my numeric facebook id. But the Graph API documentation shows that there are a lot more fields to be read, like email, gender, hometown, etc.

How can I get those fields.

I ran

```
var_dump($graphObject);
```

this was the result

```
object(Facebook\GraphObject)#5 (1) { ["backingData":protected]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(27) "Shoeb Muhammad Moniruzzaman" ["id"]=> string(17) "10206785004401959" } }
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes, “declarative fields”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the other fields, you have to ask them in the request, eg.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=name,about' );
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me?fields=name,birthday' );
```

and obviously, you have to have the permissions. [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) is very useful for these cases.